# How to print data inserted during while loop,after while loop?

Tags: c

Basically I want to be able to print data that the user input during a while loop,after said while loop.How can I achieve this?

(How the program works is,the user logs in the system and adds a bunch of details,then they are asked if they wish to continue (if they input "yes" the program continues,else it goes back to the log in screen). I want to print the info the user entered after they choose to continue)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 int main(void){

 char ans[10];

do
{
  char username[6];
  char password[6];

  bool valid = false;
  while(!valid) {
   printf("give username: \n");
   scanf("%s",&username);
   printf("give password: \n");
   scanf("%s", &password);
   if( strcmp(username, "user1") == 0 && strcmp(password, "2020") == 0 ) {
      valid = true;
   }
   else if( strcmp(username, "u") == 0 && strcmp(password, "2020c") == 0 ) { // checking if user's 
      valid = true;                                                             log in info is 
   }                                                                            correct
   else {                                                                      
      valid = false; 
   }
}

// bunch of code//

printf("give name: \n");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("give surname: \n");  //info I want to print after while loop bellow ends
scanf("%s", surname);
printf("give age: \n");
scanf("%d", &age);

printf("do you wish to contrinue?\n");
scanf("%s",ans);
system("cls");

}while(!(strcmp(ans,"yes") == 0)); // lets the program continue only if user inputs "yes"

//print said info here
```

Comment: I'm afraid that comment will sound quite "dull", but just add the line of code you want to be executed where you want to be executed (as in most programming languages...). I'm trying to guess the issue you would have because I hope to assume you already tried: you need to declare the relevant variables "in scope", so in this case `surname` would need to be declared _outside_ the loop, i.e. to be visible in the whole function and not only in the loop (as it seems the case for `username` and `password`.

Comment: @Pac0 thank you so much.I realise how dumb my question sounds right now, I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Comment: @ArMANIAK thank you for the solution.

Comment: @philipnasus You has some erros, but I think you can solve them! Like some variables note declared and yours scanfs, and where is you name/surname/age variables etc

Answer (score 1):

You should define those variables You want to use outside the loop before while-loop and later on set the value inside the loop.